# Vue.js & D3.js - Trying to call a Vue method when user clicks on svg element, but it's throwing an error

Tags: vue.js, d3.js

When the user clicks on an svg element it should trigger a method which is defined in the vue method section but that's not working. It's throwing me the error:
"Uncaught TypeError: this.renderData is not a function at SVGForeignObjectElement.eval"

My code:

````
renderData(data){
   //some other code

    svg.selectAll('.delete-icon')
    .on('click', function ({id}) {
        links = removeLinksRelations(links, id);
        nodes = nodes.filter(node => id !== node.id);
        **this.renderData({ links, nodes });**  // <--- THIS DOESN'T WORK

}}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `this` is within the scope of `function ({id}) { ... }`. If you want to call renderChart(), store the `this` referring to the vue instance before your statement.

Try:

````
renderData(data){
   const vueInstance = this
   //some other code

    svg.selectAll('.delete-icon')
    .on('click', function ({id}) {
        links = removeLinksRelations(links, id);
        nodes = nodes.filter(node => id !== node.id);
        **vueInstance.renderData({ links, nodes });**

}}```
````

Comment: This is amazing!! Thank you so much! I knew it had something to do with the scope but I didn't know how to fix it :)!